# How to change build type in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, debugging, build

I am using Android Studio and want to have two different versions of my app. One "release" version for the public and a "debug" version for developers. I have made the two build variants and can go to the "debug" build where the code is a little different. But when I run the code, the normal "main" or "release" code gets ran, its like Ive never made a "debug" and "release" version. It just runs the code like it did before. And I have to say I tried everything.

Anyone expierenced can help me out maybe?

I have tried to fix it with gradle commands and changing lines in the build.gradle. Ive changed the build variant in Android Studio 100%.

EDIT: Oh god, I just found the problem. I just had to set the exported value of the activity to "true" in the AndroidManifest so it can run.. But your answers actually helped me too, thank you!!

Comment: That's all enabled by default.  When you build by default it's a debug build.  You can check which mode its in at runtime by checking BuildConfig.  How were you doing it?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps:

*Note this is how to set up correctly, not necessarily fixing your specific error. Try undoing what you've done, and doing this. If you don't want to do that, try looking for debugging solutions in the website I provided.

Select **Build** in the top menu > Select **Build Variant** > **View** > **Tool** **Windows** > **Build Variants.**

Then, click the **Build Variants** tab on the tool window bar.

I suspect this website should also help you:

https://developer.android.com/studio/run

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add productFlavor to your app so that your **build.gradle(app-level)** file :

```
flavorDimensions "app"
productFlavors {
    appOneRelease {
        applicationId "com.example.appOneRelease"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        // you can add other flavor related configurations here
        return true
    }
    appOneDevelopment {
        applicationId "com.example.appOneDevelopment"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        // you can add other flavor related configurations here
        return true
    }
}
```